# Knockout.js removeAll function is not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, shift, removeall

Why isn't removeAll and indexOf working? Sort, splice, slice and reverse works fine.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.4.0.js'> </script>
</head>
<body>
   <table height="100" border="1" width="800">
    <tr> 
      <td>
         <span data-bind="text : array1()"></span>
     </td> 
   </tr>
 </table>
<div>
  <table height="100" border="1" width="1000">
    <tr>
      <td><button data-bind="click : sort1"   >Sort</button></td>
      <td><button data-bind="click : shift1"  >Shift</button></td>
      <td><button data-bind="click : reverse1" >Reverse</button></td>
      <td><button data-bind="click : splice1"   >Splice</button></td>
      <td><button data-bind="click : indexof1"  >IndexOf</button></td>
      <td><button data-bind="click : slice1" >Slice</button><br></td>
      <td><button data-bind="click : remove1"  >remove</button></td>
     <td><button data-bind="click : removeAll1" >removeAll</button></td>
     <td><button data-bind="click : removeFunction" >remFunction</button>/td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table height="100" border="1" width="1000">
  <tr>
     <td>Enter Text <input data-bind="value: textval"></td></input>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<span data-bind="text: textval"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myModel={
     array1 :  ko.observableArray(["animal","boy","cat","dog","elf","fox"]),
     textval   :  ko.observable(""),
     sort1 : function(){
         myModel.array1.sort();
     },

     shift1 : function(){
         alert(myModel.val());
         myModel.array1.unshift(myModel.textval());

     },
```

shift is not working properly?

```
     reverse1 : function(){
         myModel.array1.reverse();
     },

     splice1 : function(){
        alert( myModel.array1.splice(1,3));
     },
     indexof1: function(){
         alert(myModel.textval());
         alert(myModel.array1.indexOf(myModel.textval()));
     },

     slice1 : function(){
        alert( myModel.array1.slice(1,4));
     },

     removeAll1 : function(){
         alert("removall");
         myModel.array1.removeAll();
     }
```

removeAll is also not working properly. I tried many time but in JSP it is not at all working.

```
  }
  ko.applyBindings(myModel);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `shift1` method uses `unshift` internally... But more importantly: could you explain what you mean by "not working properly". Any errors logged in your console?

Comment: I am using it in eclipse indigo , on a jsp page . code simply inserts blank values, and removeAll does nothing. i tried several times for hours , searched on net , code seems to be simple and fine but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

For RemoveAll just empty the array

```
myModel.array1([]);
```

For Shifting:

```
// this is falling over -- alert(myModel.val()); <- should be myModel.textval()  
// therefore not getting to this.
myModel.array1.unshift(myModel.textval());
```

Also if you can create a JSFiddle of this.

Answer (score 0):

There is issues in your markup and your viewmodel, open the browser console on this fiddle and look at the errors for the different actions:

https://jsfiddle.net/z15d5awa/

```
     shift1 : function(){
       alert(myModel.val());
       myModel.array1.unshift(myModel.textval());
    },
```

`myModel.val()` what is this?

Comment: thank you for pointing out, actually while trying different ways , I forgot to update this section of code.yes that was a mistake!! after changing it   to "alert(myModel.textval());" it is working fine.  thank you
tyler_mitchell  ,      brettkc for your help.